# rich textbox combines all lines into one when saved as txt file?

Tags: vb.net, text, line, richtextbox

I have a rich textbox in vb.net, which contains several lines of text however when I try and save the text to a .txt file all the lines are combined into one???

How can I overcome this?

what i did try was:

```
       Dim MYLINES As Object

        For Each MYLINES In RichTextBox1.Text
        objWriter.WriteLine(MYLINES.ToString & Environment.NewLine)
    Next

objWriter.Close()
```

however this simply placed every single character on a difrent line...

Comment: Let's see the code where you save the rich edit contents.

Comment: Post your code routines that you use to LOAD and SAVE the RTF data and maybe someone can help by spotting something you may have overlooked.

Comment: My guess is that your text has one big line and word wrap is set to true, so it appears as several lines. In this case .NET is behaving exactly as it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as a .RTF file (instead of .TXT), wich can process the line breaks directly. Thats an option.

Or you can wirte the lines individually:

```
Dim sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter(sFileName)

For Each sLine as String in TextBox1.Lines
    sw.WriteLine(sLine)
Next

sw.Close()
```

The method `WriteLine` already adds a line break at the end. It more or less the same as:

```
 .Write(sLine & Enviroment.NewLine())
```